# <script type="text/javascript"> into iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, embed

All the Questions I find are more complex than this!

A site generates this code for adding social share buttons on my site:

```
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-57a28ab5d5f31c04"></script>
```

It has to be pasted in HTML inside `<body></body>`

But my web constructor online only allows me to insert a tag: `<iframe></iframe>`

I understand the basic embedding purpose of an iframe but is there a way to make that script work into the iframe?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean "my web constructor online only allows me to insert a tag: <iframe></iframe>"? If the only thing you can do is enter an `iframe` tag then there's nothing else you can do. Unless you make that `iframe` point to a page that contains that `script` tag,

Comment: That's the thing! I don't have access to the HTML on the server but I'm only allowed to insert an iframe tag code.

Technical Support of addthis.com don't offer a solution.

Thanks Mike!

Comment: Here's the thing: the only thing an `iframe` does is allow you to, essentially, embed another page into a page. So you need a page to point to it. It also won't embed that script in the main page, it will embed it in the iframes page.

Comment: True. It wasn't possible. www.mysite.com embeds the iframe.html with the js but all the share button links point to that FTP uploaded file www.domain.com/html/iframe.html and not my site: www.mysite.com with the <iframe></iframe> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it depends on what that script links to or contains references to.

I'm not sure an iframe would be all that nice to use but it should be doable. Though you might have to create a separate page with that source and then link it via iframe.

```
e.g. <iframe src="link to page with that source code eg http://www.example.com/sharebuttons.html"></iframe>
```

Edit: It's pure js so you'll want to use a script tag in the body of your doccument as is provided or you'll have to do so on another page and use an iframe to link that page.

Comment: Good idea. I'm trying that. Pasted the code into a totally clean HTML page and uploaded it via FTP but the iframe only supports HTTPS not HTTP. Anyway.. that's a different subject. I'll figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It wasn't possible. www.mysite.com finally embeds the iframe.html with the js but all the share button links point to that FTP uploaded file www.domain.com/html/iframe.html and not my site: www.mysite.com with the <iframe></iframe>

Thanks @Edmazing